# Have a subdirectory in an external domain point to a rails app without URL change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-rewriting, http-redirect, url-mapping

I have a rails app hosted on Heroku at, say, app.herokuapp.com

I would like to know if there is a way to have an URL such as www.external.com/app that points to my rails app but does not redirect. Just masks the URL and nobody ever knows that the app is really hosted at another domain, different from external.com.

Though about an iframe, but it is not a very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on what server you are using. If you are using Apache, then you might want to take a look at [Domain forwarding in Apache](http://shapeshed.com/domain_forwarding_in_apache/).

Comment: Wouldn't that change the URL in the address bar?

Comment: Part of the guide is sending a 301 whenever an alternative domain is hit. Sending the 301 will change the URL. If you are using Apache, you can set up multiple virtual hosts to point to the same rails application. These named virtual hosts will correspond to the Domains your clients want.